# Presenting an SKScene from within another SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Inside my main UIViewController, I'm defining two SKScenes. I want to present only `gameScene` at first, and then present `uiScene` later, triggered by an action in `gameScene` (hitting the pause button).

The problem is that `skView`, the view containing both scenes, is not recognized outside of the UIViewController.

The code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as SKView

    let gameScene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    gameScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    skView.presentScene(gameScene)

    let uiScene = UIScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    uiScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    uiScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    //skView.presentScene(uiScene)  // I want to present this line from within gameScene.

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = uiScene(size: size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

You can transition from one scene to another from within the scene.  My code is pulled from http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners in the last section.

Remember to import the header of the scene you are transitioning TO in the scene you are transitioning FROM.