# Present an SKScene from itself

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I am trying to figure out how I can present an SKScene from itself, in effect reloading it. First of all, I would like to ask if there is a more efficient way of reloading a scene. I could not find one, so I resorted to finding a way to present an SKScene from another SKScene.

After searching around the Glorious Internet for a while, I found this ([Presenting an SKScene from within another SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637052/presenting-an-skscene-from-within-another-skscene)) question.

Here is the code that  I currently have, inspired by the code posted in the answer to the above question:

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
let scene = self.scene
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

This yields no errors initially, but when I build it and this action (to present the scene) is called, there is an error of NSException.

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does anybody know of a simple way that I can in effect reload a scene (from itself). If not, does anybody know how I can easily present a scene from itself?

Thanks so much in advance! Any response is well appreciated!

Comment: Try adding this line of code `let viewer = self.view as SKView!` and then calling it in `viewer.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)` i'm not sure why it crashes but maybe this might work, you never know.

Comment: Why do you want to present a scene from itself? Do you want to present another instance of the same SKScene subclass?

Answer (score 0):

In, the code you have posted, you have written:

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
let scene = self.scene //<- This is causing your issue
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

The error is caused because you are presenting a scene which already is attached to an SKView.

You cannot present a scene from itself. Possibly, you want to present another instance of the same scene?

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
let scene = GameScene(size: self.size) //Replace GameScene with current class name
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```